# to find who logged in first in given interval of time sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization

This is a dummy script :

```
create table #tempLogs (
UserId int identity(1,1) primary key,
LoggedAt DateTime not null
)
insert into #tempLogs values(getdate())
insert into #tempLogs values(getdate()-0.05)
insert into #tempLogs values(getdate()+0.0075)
select * from #tempLogs

SELECT top 1 UserId, (SUBSTRING((CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), LoggedAt)),13,5)) 
from #tempLogs
order by 2 


drop table #tempLogs
```

How can I optimize :

```
SELECT top 1 UserId, (SUBSTRING((CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), LoggedAt)),13,5)) 
    from #tempLogs


where between @StartDate and @EndDate -- for some time interval. These are inputs  & need to be passed

order by 2
```

> > Top 1 is actually not a right solution there can be more than 1 User coming on same minute i.e. 9:27 9:27 
> >  
> >  
> >     Here, temptables are just used actually query would be fired on actual tables & not temporary.
> >  
> >  
> >     Need advice on  optimizing this.

Example  :

```
UserId  LoggedAt
1       2011-12-22 11:44:31.037
2       2011-12-22 10:32:31.040
3       2011-12-22 11:55:19.040
4       2011-12-22 10:32:31.040

Output

2       2011-12-22 10:32:31.040
4       2011-12-22 10:32:31.040
```

thats it!

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, please tag it as such.

Comment: "Top 1 is actually not a right solution there can be more than 1 User coming on same minute" - so what do you *want* to do in this situation? How is your current solution broken? We're not mind-readers.

Comment: Also, your question title talks about querying in an interval, which would generally suggest some form of filtering, but you've not given any indication of what filtering is required.

Comment: like @Damien_The_Unbeliever stated, what do you mean by interval of time? Every minute, every hour??

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, aF : Please see my updated question for the filtering. CodeBrickie : Its NOT a homework question but you can tag it if you want. I just thought that SO is for asking best practices for coding, which I have asked in this question.

Comment: @Pratik - the query at the end of my answer should contain what's wanted, if not, then you'll have to try and be more clear on what's required.

Comment: @Pratik - I didn't downvote myself, but you've asked a *very* vague question, it's taken a lot of work to get close to understanding what you're asking for. I'm now on my 3rd and 4th possible answers to your question, and still not 100% sure that I've hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the User with the minimal LoggedAt value is like this:

```
create table #tempLogs (
UserId int identity(1,1) primary key,
LoggedAt DateTime not null
)
insert into #tempLogs values(getdate())
insert into #tempLogs values(getdate()-0.05)
insert into #tempLogs values(getdate()+0.0075)


SELECT UserId, convert(varchar(5), LoggedAt, 108)
from #tempLogs
where LoggedAt = (select min(LoggedAt) from #tempLogs)




drop table #tempLogs
```

Comment: I want to get User with minimum  (hh:MM)  & not all !!

Answer (score 1):

### Current best guess at the required answer:

If you need to get the first "with ties", then:

```
;WITH RankedLogs as (
    SELECT ID,LoggedAt,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LoggedAt) as rn
    from #tempLogs where LoggedAt between @StartDate and @EndDate
)
SELECT * from RankedLogs where rn = 1
```

Or, if two logins within the same minute should rank together then:

```
;WITH RankedLogs as (
    SELECT ID,LoggedAt,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,0,LoggedAt),0)) as rn
    from #tempLogs where LoggedAt between @StartDate and @EndDate
)
SELECT * from RankedLogs where rn = 1
```

---

Previous answers:

Completely random guess - you want to find the earliest login within each hour long interval. Assuming same setup script as per your question:

```
;With RankedLogins as (
    Select UserID,LoggedAt,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,LoggedAt),0) ORDER BY LoggedAt) as rn
    from #tempLogs
)
select * from RankedLogins where rn = 1
```

Result from table setup:

```
UserId  LoggedAt
1       2011-12-22 11:44:31.037
2       2011-12-22 10:32:31.040
3       2011-12-22 11:55:19.040
```

And results:

```
UserID  LoggedAt                rn
2       2011-12-22 10:32:31.040 1
1       2011-12-22 11:44:31.037 1
```

To find who logged in first on each day, change the two instances of `hour` in the above query to `day`.

---

For your simpler question (basically, find the earliest row between `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`), it could just be:

```
SELECT top 1 * from #tempLogs
where LoggedAt between @StartDate and @EndDate
order by LoggedAt
```

Comment: For above given data result required is only :  2       2011-12-22 10:32:31.040 & not all! I hope you got what the required result is!